# How do I give "#ffff" string color to setBackgroundColor() as parameter?

Tags: android

I want to give color to relative layout as `setBackgroundColor()` and the color value is like `"#ffffff"` and `setBackgroundColor()` dosent accept string value

Comment: By the way... `g` is not a valid hex digit, so nothing should accept `"#Fgfff"`.

Comment: oops that was typo mistake , its #ffffff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can Use the below code:-

```
Relativelayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout` doesn't have the `setCardBackgroundColor` method.